# subplot with plotly with multiple traces

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

i am trying to create subplots for the following plots:

[image]

[image]

the code i used for the the plots are  :

```
radius_mean1 = df[df['diagnosis']==1]['radius_mean']
radius_mean0 = df[df['diagnosis']==0]['radius_mean']

trace_rm1 = go.Histogram(x = radius_mean1, opacity = 0.75, name = 'malignant')
trace_rm2 = go.Histogram(x = radius_mean0, opacity = 0.75, name = 'benign')

data2 = [trace_rm1,trace_rm2]
layout2 = go.Layout(barmode = 'overlay', title = 'radius mean')
fig2 = go.Figure(data=data2, layout=layout2)

py.iplot(fig2)
```

and similar for the other plot

now i use the following code i found to create subplots:

```
fig.append_trace(fig1['data'][1], 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)
py.iplot(fig)
```

and i get this :
[image]

how do i add both benign and malignant results to the subplots ?
i cant seem to edit the [0] or [ 1] to show both ie have the first 2 plots exactly into my subplot showing both malignant and benign and not just one or the other.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The data here is not complete, so I using some demo data to present.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly

a = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
b = np.random.normal(-2,5,100)

c = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
d = np.random.normal(-2,5,100)

fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2,cols=1)

trace_rm1 = go.Histogram(x = a, opacity = 0.75, name = 'malignant')
trace_rm2 = go.Histogram(x = b, opacity = 0.75, name = 'benign')
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x = a, opacity = 0.75, name = 'benign'),1,1)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x = b, opacity = 0.75, name = 'malignant'),1,1)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x = c, opacity = 0.75, name = 'benign'),2,1)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x = d, opacity = 0.75, name = 'malignant'),2,1)
fig.layout.update(go.Layout(barmode = 'overlay',))

plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Would it be possible to give each of the two plots a title?

Comment: @A.P. Of course, you could just fill the param of `plotly.tools.make_subplots`, there is a param called `subplot_titles`. It actually adds two annotations automatically for you.

Comment: For the subplot in row=1, column=1: can you shorten the commands for plotting the 2 histograms, so that they fit into 1 line? Or can you have one command for plotting multiple histograms at once?

Comment: @NeStack but first you need to have a combined data with indicator of different groups? or something else. you could see the plotly express for help I think. https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/